# Extract data from specific format in Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a raw data in csv format which looks like this:

`product-name    brand-name   rating`

`["Whole Wheat"] ["bb Royal"] ["4.1"]`

Expected output:

`product-name   brand-name   rating`

`Whole Wheat    bb Royal     4.1`

I want this to affect every entry in my dataset. I have 10,000 rows of data. How can I do this using pandas?
Can we do this using regular expressions? Not sure how to do it.

Thank you.

Edit 1:
My data looks something like this:

```
df = {
'product-name': [
[""'Whole Wheat'""], [""'Milk'""] ],

'brand-name': [
[""'bb Royal'""], [""'XYZ'""] ],

'rating': [
[""'4.1'""], [""'4.0'""] ]
 }
df_p = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
```

It outputs like this: ["bb Royal"]

PS: Apologies for my programming. I am quite new to programming and also to this community. I really appreciate your help here :)

Comment: What is `print (df.head()).to_dict())` ?

Comment: You say csv, but it looks like the data is sepperated by spaces? I may just be confused here

Comment: I have updated the comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC select first values of lists:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str[0])
```

Or if values are strings:

```
df = df.replace('[\[\]]', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: It outputs like this: "Whole Wheat"
I need to remove the double inverted commas too.

Comment: It worked after I have replaced the regular expression with  
`'["\["\]]'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function

```
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```